# Is it possible to add View into included layout in xml?

Tags: android, android-layout

I was wondering if the following could be achieved in xml:

I have this simple layout like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="Address: "
    android:textSize="14dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When I include this layout in other xml, is it possible to add another TextView in it, so the result would look like:

Address: Text of another textview.

I would like to get this done in xml, not programmatically.

I've tried following:

```
            <include layout="@layout/mybaselayout" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:text="mylocalizedstring" />
            </include>
```

That ain't working, am I trying something impossible here to do in xml ?

Thanks.

Comment: If i'm not mistaken you should be able to put a textview right below the current one.

Comment: Then you should add textView to this layout... But i'd say that programmatically would be much easier to do it.

Comment: But I have case where there are like 40 localized strings used for the second text, but the first text is always the same. So I'm trying to use less code.

Comment: I updated the description little bit, hopefully you understand what I'm trying to do here. Just wanna know if this is possible some way in xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the way I want to add views inside included layout in xml is not possible, only way to achieve it, is to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
          android:orientation="vertical"  
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
    >  
<TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:text="This is a 'sans' demo!"  
        android:typeface="sans"  
        />  
 <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:text="This is a 'serif' demo!"  
        android:typeface="serif"  
        />  
 <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:text="This is a 'monospace' demo!"  
        android:typeface="monospace"  
        />  

  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use some coding if you don't want to directly add `TextView` in your `xml` layout file. If you are including your layout more than once and you want to add `TextView` only some times use [ViewStub](http://android-developers.blogspot.sk/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-with.html).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Address: "
        android:textSize="14dp" />
    <ViewStub
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/view_stub"
        android:inflatedId="@+id/addr"
        android:layout="@layout/text_view" />
</LinearLayout>
```

`text_view.xml` layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

When you want to display `TextView` you inflate it with

```
TextView text_view = (TextView) ((ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.view_stub)).inflate();
text_view.setText(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can surely do this way in your second xml file,

```
<RelativeLayout>
<include android:id="@+id/llone" layout="@layout/topbar"/>
<TextView android:layout_toRightOf="@id/llone"></TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `<include>` tag

```
<include layout="@layout/topbar" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Yes I'm including that layout, but I also want to add another TextView inside it in xml.